# Is there a PHP base for aiding in hosting things like client preview images, videos, and etc?

Tags: php, open-source

I am trying to find a system/platform to build off of to make it easy for members of my team to upload images, video, and etc to a simple password protected site so that they can easily and privately share works in progress with clients without having build a static page every time.

Thank you!

***Additional Note**:
Ideally something a touch closer than a base framework like Zend or CodeIgniter, but they could be libraries for them.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [FileRun](http://www.filerun.com/)

Allows you to create permissions, clients and let both sides upload / download files. We use that at our company.